# Time series frequency in ts function using r

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I am trying it hard to understand frequency setup in ts function using r when i have my time series dataset which is recorded every 15 mins between a time interval in a day which changes from day to day for example one day the data is recorded between 6 am till 9 am and another day it will be betwee 10am and 10 pm for 5 years. If this is the case, how do I set my frequency value in ts function? Please advise.
[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzJ4v.png)

Thank you.

Regards,
Anil

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure.  I have a transaction data recorded every 15 mins for 5 years between a time interval in a day as shown above. My goal is to forecast for the following month on 15 minute interval. I have used prophet library in r to model this and it worked. Now, I am trying to model it using forecast library in r. But, I am facing it hard to use ts function due to the nature of my data

Comment: I have attached data in my main post. Please click on "Raw Data" above.

Comment: You might be better off using fable (and tsibble). Fable is the successor of forecast and works with time aware tibbles. The time periods are better interpretable than the ts timeframes. More info [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/)